# Incorrect file type being uploaded to Cloud Storage, despite specifying file extension

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-storage

When I upload an image to Cloud Storage, I remember to specify that I want a PNG file uploaded, but it still uploads a JPEG.

```
String privatePath = "privateFoodImages/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".png"; 
final StorageReference privateReference = firebaseStorage.getReference(privatePath);
```

The weird part is, it only does this on an emulator. When I test the same code and security rules on my actual device, it works, taking whatever file extension I specify and converting it to a PNG. But it won't convert to a PNG on the emulator. Any idea what's causing this?

[image: Here's two images in Cloud Storage.] The first was from the emulator, and the second was from my device.

Comment: Are you sure the file got converted to PNG? Just because you renamed the extension doesn't mean it is actually a PNG.

Comment: @drum I haven't needed to convert them in the past. On my physical device, I could select any file type (such as JPEG) from my gallery, and it would automatically turn into a PNG upon being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this a bit more, and found a solution. As @drum pointed out below my original comment, it was a PNG in the database because I wasn't converting it to a PNG before the upload. It's weird, because on my device, I could just specify .png and it would do the rest. For those struggling with it, here's the working code I am now using.

```
    // This paragraph will compress the image into a JPEG
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
        byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();



    // This paragraph will turn the compressed image back into the superior file type (PNG)
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.length);
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
       byte[] pngByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

Then you can just take byte[] pngByteArray and upload it to Cloud Storage using `<STORAGE_REFERENCE>.putBytes(pngByteArray);`